# How to create a Multi-Network subsite?

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I've enabled Wordpress Multisite (subdomains) on www.example.com, and installed/enabled [WP Multi-Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/).

I've created a new network @ `s.example.com`.

How do I create a subsite in that network, e.g. `s.example.com/subsite`?

`s.example.com/wp-admin/network` redirects to `www.example.com/wp-admin/network`.

If I create a new site @ `www.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, I can't make it a subdomain or subdirectory of `s.example.com`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? You should just be able to go to Sites/Add New

Comment: @NathanPowell: If I create a new site @ www.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php, I can't make it a subdomain or subdirectory of s.example.com (a member of the s.example.com network) - there is no functionality to do this.

Comment: I see. Are you able to create any subsites or see the network admin? Is this question about the plugin and NOT WordPress?

Comment: I can see network admin and create subsites fine. I can't create a subsite in a network, e.g. `s.example.com/subsite`.

Answer (score 0):

With the multisite install main site and network on **s.example.com**
you can have the subiste as **s.example.com/subsite**

you will need to have your multisite as a sub-folder installation and not a sub-domain installation ([ref the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network))

As you are using WP-Multi-Network you should be ok to go to create a new site @ `s.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php`.  Otherwise if the site has already been created on the Multisite installation go to `s.example.com/wp-admin/network/admin.php?page-networks` edit the network for s.example.com and select from the available sites the one(s) that you want to add to the s.example.com network.

Comment: This is false. You can have a sub domain as the main site.

Comment: @Nathan-powell - Thanks I've revisited subdomains on the main site and I have seen you are right.  I've never got this to work before, most likely due to a missing DNS A record. I'll update my Answer.

Comment: I can't get to `s.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php` - it redirects to `www.example.com/wp-admin/network/`.

Comment: I went through and installed a sub-domain set-up and tested the answer given.  do you have two networks one for 'example.com' and a second for 's.example.com' ?

Comment: Hi @Justin, been a while! I found out I had a cPanel subdomain `s.example.com` overriding the wildcard subdomain `*.example.com`. I deleted the subdomain `s.example.com` and now `s.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php` loads fine. However, I cannot create a subsite as a subdirectory of `s.example.com` - it has to be a subdomain.